# AngularJs close modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I wan create function to close modal . I try some thing like this .

Code for open the modal

```
$scope.showPreloader = function() {
        $scope.$modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: false,
            templateUrl: preloaderTemplate,
            size: 'sm',
            windowClass: 'preloader',
        })
    };
```

To hide modal

```
$scope.hidePreloader = function() {
      $scope.$modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
```

The modal only open and not close it . I run them like this .

```
 $scope.simulateLoader = function(message) {
          var runIns = $scope.showPreloader();
          setTimeout(function () {
                $scope.hidePreloader();
            }, 2000);
        }
```

The close function didn't work.

Edit: I think the close function is run . It only not remove the modal . I set backdrop to false . Backdrop cant be click during that time out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Angular `$timeout` instead of `window.setTimeout`, because `$timeout` will call `$scope.$apply` to trigger `$digest` and update the view:

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.hidePreloader();
}, 2000);
```

Remember to inject `$timeout` when declaring the controller, say:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout)...
```

Comment: @SahalSaad My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
    $scope.showPreloader = function() {
            $scope.$modalInstance = $modal.open({
                animation: false,
                templateUrl: preloaderTemplate,
                size: 'sm',
                windowClass: 'preloader',
                scope: $scope,
                controller: ['$scope','$modalInstance', function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
                          $scope.hidePreloader = function () {
                            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                          };
                  }
            })
        };
```

and then call your `$scope.hidePreloader` method to dismiss modal popup